# Fundamental differences between digital ID and SSL security certificates

Tags: tls

I was reading http://www.symantec.com/verisign/digital-id and  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351044(v=exchg.150).aspx. The articles are treating ssl cert and 'digital id' as if they are two different concepts. I was under the impression that they were the same thing, just different names.

Are there any differences between Digital Ids and SSL Encryption/Digital Certificates?

Comment: The linked document does not include the phrase "Digital ID".

Comment: @GrahamHill My apologies, it appears I was looking at http://www.symantec.com/verisign/digital-id as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SSL certificate" is an informal name used to refer to the X.509 Digital certificate that is used when communicating over the SSL protocol.

"Digital ID" is a Symantec product name. They don't give much technical information about what it is, but it sounds like an X.509 certificate that you can use for various things, mainly encrypting/signing emails or word documents.

So, they are (probably) the same thing, but are being used for (probably) different purposes.